# How to create and execute a batch file in vbscript?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I tried to do it this way:

```
Dim objFSO, outFile, wshShell
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("paint.bat", True)
outFile.WriteLine "taskkill /f /im mspaint.exe"
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Run "paint.bat", 0, false
```

that was to work but of an error saying "The file is already being used by another process"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is already being used by your own `cscript` or `wscript` process. You should use  `outFile.Close` (and maybe moreover `Set outFile = Nothing`) before `run`.

Answer (score 0):

Terminates paint directly in vbscript.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
For Each objItem in colItems
    If objitem.Name = "mspaint.exe" Then
        msgbox objitem.name & " PID=" & objItem.ProcessID & " SessionID=" & objitem.sessionid
        objitem.terminate
    End If
Next
```